# Flood control IP bypass whitelist

Tags: users, services

I am utilising Services to open up some login resources on my site and as a result if multiple users incorrectly try to sign in the entire external website will be blocked because of flood control.

Is there a way to add an IP whitelist to the flood so that there can be an unlimited number of requests from those IPs without them being blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Try [flood_unblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_unblock) module and [flood_control](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_control) I think both will help you with your requirements, choose the best based on your use case.

Comment: Ive tried both these modules, but they are a one change for all users/ips. I want to be able to create a whitelist so that specific IPs never go into flood. My workaround at the moment until i find a more elegant solution is to clear the flood if it matches a specific IP, so as to never block that address.